# Renaming Heroku app broke email using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I renamed my Rails app on Heroku using CLI/terminal command:
 heroku apps:rename newname

Now when I try to reset passwords on the application, it still points to the old app name. Do I need to run a process or go through another step to point the password reset at the new app name?

Comment: How did you go with this? I just encountered this problem and am trying to figure it out :)